# Inherit static methods in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Using ES6 syntax is it possible to extend a class and inherit its static methods? And if so, can we call super in the subclass's static method?

Example:

```
class Parent {
  static myMethod(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static myMethod() {
    super("hello")
  }
}

Child.myMethod();  // logs "hello"
```

This is giving me a no method *call* on undefined error in my transpiler (Reactify).

`____SuperProtoOfParent.open.call(this);`

Comment: Note that it is illegal to call `super` outside constructors. You would want to have `super.myMethod()` here, but I don't know if `super`  is supposed to work works in static methods.

Comment: Interesting question, but looking at this from an OOP point of view shouldn't you just call `Parent.myMethod()` since `static` implies no instance?

Answer (score 25):

According to the [spec here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-getsuperbase) and [here](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-makesuperpropertyreference) `super` base references to the prototype of the current `this` object. In static methods it will reference to the inherited class . So to invoke the parent static method you must call `super.myMethod('some message')`. Here is an example:

```
class Parent {
  static myMethod(msg) {
    console.log('static', msg);
  }

  myMethod(msg) {
    console.log('instance', msg);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static myMethod(msg) {
    super.myMethod(msg);
  }

  myMethod(msg) {
    super.myMethod(msg);
  }
}

Child.myMethod(1); // static 1
var child = new Child(); 

child.myMethod(2); // instance 2
```

[Here is the es6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/i82oshrt/)